# Access parent element by variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var _div = $("<div id='ds-tree-expand'/>").appendTo( "#ds-subject-tree" );
var _cur_token = "susmita";
var _next_token = "sudipta";

for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    var _1st_level = $( "<p id='acc_trigger' class='active collapsed'>" + _cur_token + "</p>" ).appendTo(_div);
    var _2nd_level = $( "<p id='2nd_trigger' class='active collapsed'>" + _next_token + "</p>" ).appendTo(_1st_level);
}

var _2nd_ch = _div.children().children();
```

Now I want to access the **parent** of each `_2nd_ch` element.
I have tried:

```js
$(_2nd_ch[1]).parent();
```

This isn't working.  How can I access the **parent** of each item of the `_2nd_ch` array?

Comment: `_2nd_ch.each(function(i, el){ $(el).parent() })`

Comment: I want to access the Text part of parent element.
**var _ab = _2nd_ch.each(function(i, el){ $(el).parent() });
alert(_ab);**
But it's not working properly.

Comment: `parent()` returns an jQuery object that contains a parent element. You can use any jQuery method on it, like `parent.text()` or `parent.html()`

Answer (score 0):

See this might helpful to you. http://jsfiddle.net/z8a0234b/ You can access any node using `_nth`.

```js
var _div = $("<div id='ds-tree-expand'/>").appendTo( "#ds-subject-tree" );
var _cur_token = "Parent";
var _next_token = "Child";

for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    var _1st_level = $( "<p id='acc_trigger' class='active collapsed'>" + _cur_token + " "+ i +"</p>" ).appendTo(_div);
    var _2nd_level = $( "<p id='2nd_trigger' class='active collapsed'>" + _next_token + " "+ i +"</p>" ).appendTo(_1st_level);
}

var _nth = 2;/*2dn node, for Parent 1*/
var _nth_parent = $("#ds-tree-expand > #acc_trigger:nth-child("+_nth+")").html();
_nth_parent = _nth_parent.split("<p"); _nth_parent = _nth_parent[0]; /*filter to trace only words no tag*/
var _nth_child = $("#ds-tree-expand > #acc_trigger:nth-child("+_nth+") > p").html();

alert(_nth_parent +" "+ _nth_child);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ds-subject-tree"></div>
```